# Need to check array of object in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of objects inside an array and I have to check status of each object and return a single value for each array.

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {projId: 1, task: 'task 1', status: 'completed'}
1: {projId: 1, task: 'task 2', status: 'completed'}
2: {projId: 1, task: 'task 3', status: 'completed'}
3: {projId: 1, task: 'task 4', status: 'completed'}
4: {projId: 1, task: 'task 5', status: 'completed'}
5: {projId: 1, task: 'task 6', status: 'completed'}
6: {projId: 1, task: 'task 7', status: 'completed'}
7: {projId: 1, task: 'task 8', status: 'completed'}
8: {projId: 1, task: 'task 9', status: 'completed'}
9: {projId: 1, task: 'task 10', status: 'completed'}
```

Need to check the status, and if it is completed for the whole array then return `competed` else return `in progress`. The code I tried is given below, but that returns for each object in array.

```
{GroupedData[key].map(status => ((status.status === "completed")? "Completed" : "In Progress"))}
```

And I am writing this inside the return of export function in React.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` method is used to **change** values in a given array and returns that new modified array. In your case, your code changes each value in your array to `completed` / `in progress` depending on the status of the object.

In your case, I think that using `.some()` or `.every()` will be the best way to go about this. In the code below you are checking that every project has status `completed` and if that returns true it assigns `'completed'` to `result`, if not it assigns `'in progress'`

```
const result = data.every((project) => project.status === 'completed') ? 'completed' : 'in progress';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
yourArrayObject.every((itemObject) => itemObject.status === 'completed') ? 'Completed' : 'In Progress';
```

Answer (score 0):

All the `map` function does is to take an array and return a modified one. You could use the `some` function with it, like so:

```js
let GroupedData = [
  [
    { projId: 1, task: "task 1", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 1, task: "task 2", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 1, task: "task 3", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 1, task: "task 4", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 1, task: "task 5", status: "completed" }
  ],
  [
    { projId: 2, task: "task 1", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 2, task: "task 2", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 2, task: "task 3", status: "completed" },
    { projId: 2, task: "task 4", status: "in progres" },
    { projId: 2, task: "task 5", status: "completed" }
  ]
];
let result = GroupedData.map((d) =>
  d.some((p) => p.status !== "completed") ? "In Progress" : "Completed"
);
console.log(result);
```